# Can't find mitmproxy-ca-cert.pem

Tags: networking, certificate, packets, sniffing, mitmproxy

I installed mitmproxy on a Mac and a Linux but I can't seem to find the certificate. All tutorials seem to assume it is downloaded upon installation but I can't find it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [mitmproxy documentation](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/latest/certinstall.html):

> The mitmproxy CA cert is located in ~/.mitmproxy after it has been generated at the first start of mitmproxy.

I.e. you need to run Mitmproxy at least once for this directory to appear.

Comment: I tried to run this but I get that its not a directory! I need to install this certificate in my iPhone so that I can intercept packets coming from it to my local router. The bigger goal is to test if one of my apps sends raw locations data (longitude & latitude) to my local router! I want to make sure its not sending out my location for everyone without encryption!

Comment: Look at the documentation link above. The recommened way is to visit `mitm.it` while being proxied and install the certificate there.